# Grouped random order in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table name Employees with two columns, case id and owner. I need to write a query to select random 5 caseids for every name in owner column.

Owners name are non sorted and also caseid are unique.

Also if anyone can explain using ranking over partition by in this case?

I tried this code but its not working using self join.

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select top 5 id
               from t as t2
               where t2.name = t.name
               order by Rnd(-Timer()*[ID])
              );
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have specify the table in the subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select top 5 t2.id
               from t as t2
               where t2.name = t.name
               order by Rnd(-Timer()*t2.[ID])
              );
```